# Convergence of a rational function

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find out under which conditions does a sum of a rational function $\sum f(n)$ converges, with $f(x) = \frac{A(x)}{B(x)}$ , with $\deg B > \deg A$ and $\forall X, B(X) \neq 0 $.

Any ideas? I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have any assumptions on $A(x)$ and $B(x)$? Are they polynomials?

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini no, those are just assumptions that I made to try to go foward. The original question only states "does $\sum f(n)$ converges, with $f$ a rational function with no real poles"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as convergence is concerned, assume that we're summing $\sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n)$ where $N$ is large enough so that $B(n)\neq 0$ for $n\geq N$ and $f(n)$ is always well-defined.

If $f(n)\leq0$ for large $n$ then consider $-f(n)$ instead. We have $f(n)\sim C\frac{n^{\deg A}}{n^{\deg B}} = C\cdot \frac{1}{n^{\deg B-\deg A}}$ so that by comparison this series is convergent precisely when $\deg B-\deg A > 1$, that is $\deg B \geq \deg A+2$.